# Laravel redirect to new url playing with url parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

Laravel is doing something unsual. I have a url as follow:

```
https://www.sample-site.com/api/something/abcsafety/192
```

Laravel redirects to following url:

```
https://www.sample-site.com/api/something/abcsaf/safety
```

If I pass anything else in parameter it works. For example:

```
https://www.sample-site.com/api/something/abcsafe/192
```

is working fine.

I have noticed that it is trimming 7 characters form url (consider url as string) and appending **/safety** after that if safety keyword is in url.

I have already checked middleware, controller, app service provider. It still redirects after adding die statement in all files.

It redirects and show my die statement result.

EDIT: My route file as asked

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

#paths
Route::middleware('allowedhost')->get('/something/flushall', 'SomethingController@flushAll');
Route::middleware('allowedhost')->post('/something/deletekeys', 'SomethingController@deleteSomethingKeys');
Route::middleware('allowedhost')->get('/something/{table}/{value}', 'SomethingController@updateSomething');
#end
```

Comment: You're going to need to provide at the very least your routes file in order for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: @Joe I really need to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated. Downvoting has decreased views on issue.

Comment: does it happen if you remove `middleware('allowedhost')` from the route?

Comment: @Erich yes it still happens

Comment: post your controller method

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to the problem. It was because of a middleware which was added to the kernal.php file. And a function was called to replace seven characters from route containing safety and do the thing.

Thanks for help